# Tornado Websocket Instances behind a Load Balancer (Nginx, HaProxy)

Tags: nginx, websocket, tornado

I have previously used **Tornado** behind **Nginx** in production, that too with **multiple tornado instances**, but presently with **Websockets** implementation in Tornado, I am unable to understand few things.

> **NOTE :** Just running Websockets with Tornado is not my problem, I can get it to work and have used it in many projects fairly easily,
>   but all as a single Tornado instance with/without a reverse-proxy or
>   load balancer (nginx), both working fine.

With that said, my doubts are regarding **how to handle multiple tornado websocket instances behind a load balancer**. Lets look at a ***use case***:

**Use Case :** 2 Tornado Websocket Instances, **T1** and **T2** behind Nginx and there are 3 Clients (Browsers), lets say **C1**, **C2**, **C3**.

```
                                     ______|-------|      
 C1-----------------|               |      |  T1   |
                    |               |      |_______|       
 C2-----------------|---> Nginx --->|       
                    |               |      |-------| 
 C3-----------------|               |______|  T2   |   
                                           |_______|
```

**Step 1 -** **`C1`** initiated a websocket connection, at location **`w.x.y.z:80`**. Now Nginx load balanced the connection to lets say **`T1`**, which triggered the ***`open`*** event in ***T1's(Tornado's)*** websocket handler. Now **T1** knows of a websocket connection object which is opened, let the object be **`w1`**.

**Step 2 -** Now, **`C2`** initiated a websocket connection, same as above, but now Nginx laod balanced it to **`T2`** which triggered ***T2's(Tornado's)*** websocket handler's ***`open`*** event. Now **T2** knows of a websocket connection object which is opened, let the object be **`w2`**.

**Step 3 -** Now, similarly **`C3`** initiated a websocket connection, Nginx load balanced it to **T1**, which now has a new opened websocket connection object, let the object be **`w3`**.

**Step 4 -** Now, **`C1`**, our first client sent a message via the browser's **`ws.send()`** method, where **`ws`** is the browser(client) side's websocket object used to create the websocket connection in ***Step 1***. So when the message reached **Nginx**, it load balanced it to **T2**.

*`Now here is my question.`*

> Does Nginx load balance it to T2 or does it know that it should proxy
>   the request to T1 itself?

Suppose it sends it to **T2**, now **T2** doesn't have the **`w1`** object with it, since it is with **T1**, so when **T2's** websocket handler tries to process the request, which should originally trigger the **`on_message`** handler, so now,

> what happens at this condition, does T2 raise an Exception or what
>   happens exactly?
>
> Also, how to manage the websocket connections in these cases when there
>   are **multiple tornado instances running behind a load balancer**, *how to
>   solve this*?

If suppose we use **`Redis`** as a solution, then what would **redis** actually store? ***`The websocket objects?`*** Or, **what exactly should it store to let the instances work properly, if `Redis` is one of the solutions you are going to propose**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages are always attached to a connection; they are not load-balanced separately. So in step 4, nginx sends the message on the C1 connection to T1, not T2.

Comment: So that means whenever we create a WS connection in Tornado, load-balancing is of no use? Because, suppose both Torando instances have equal number of WS connections balanced by Nginx initially, and then most(lets say all) of WS connections to one of the Tornado instances get closed, so now, whenever WS messages are sent (the open ones), they all will be sent to the Tornado instance which created those WS connections, thus, we can say that there is no load balancing happening, and a single instance is hit with all the WS requests making no use of Nginx's load balancing?

Comment: Also, I know messages are attached to a connection, but how does nginx know what connections are initiated by which backend app server, or does it store those info? I am not sure of this.

Comment: Load balancing only comes into play when a new connection is created. It may get imbalanced e.g. when a server restarts, but in the long run it will smooth out as new connections are opened and old ones closed. Nginx tracks the mapping between its client and backend connections internally.

Comment: Okay. So if nginx tracks the connections, then its great. I didn't know about this. I had idea about how nginx can be made to track sticky sessions via some added modules. If nginx does this internally, then its good. But I am still not sure of it. If you are sure then it lessens my doubts.